# Jquery detect click and close nav

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mobile menu that works fine however when I have links that are anchors, the menu doesn't close.

I've added an event listener but I think I may have the logic wrong.

The functionality should be: when a user clicks a `li` within the `div`, go to it's intended page. If the link is an anchor then go to the page and close the menu.

Code is:

```
$('.mobile-menu-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mobileMenu').slideToggle('slow');

    $(this).addEventListener('click', function() {
        $('#mobileMenu').slideToggle('fast');
    })
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pq9ubasz/1/

Comment: in your jsfiddle I cannot see any element with a class named 'mobile-menu-button'. Attach the event to the intended element.

Comment: There is no `.mobile-menu-button` class in your html (in your fiddle). So your event listener will not be affected to an element and you won't prevent the navigation at all. Furthermore, you are creating a new eventlistener each time you click on the menu-mobile-button. There is something wrong here...

Comment: Apologies: Have updated the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/pq9ubasz/1/

Comment: you fiddle says $ is not defined , have you included jquery?

Comment: Updated the  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq9ubasz/2/). Check whether this is what you actually wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$('#mobileMenu a, .mobile-menu-button').click(function() {
    $('#mobileMenu').slideToggle();
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pq9ubasz/4/

Comment: @TinoMThomas just edit my answer if you don't like it

Comment: I am just saying that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to prevent propagation of the link. You can just close the menu upon a click on any of the list items with

```
$('#mobile-menu li').click(function() {
    $('#mobileMenu').slideToggle('fast');
});
```